# Play Framework - dev server shutting down after refreshing

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

My problem is that every time I run `sbt run`, the server works until I refresh the page. After that, I get this in my terminal

```
Uncaught error from thread [play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for for ActorSystem[play-dev-mode]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
```

Since there's not much ressources about play and scala on the web, I really need guidance for this.

Comment: This is a Java thing. Start googling for "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter".

Comment: Have you already switched to JDK9? java.xml.bind module is not resolved by default if you are using new module feature. If you need JAXB either revert back to JDK8 or run with --add-modules java.xml.bind or else deploy JAXB on the class path

Comment: Thanks I made it work. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: How did you make it work? I'm having the same issue, I've added to build.sbt `javaOptions in Universal ++= "--add-modules=java.xml.bind"` and it compiles, but doesn't run.

Comment: I've posted an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I resolved my issue with `libraryDependencies += "javax.xml.bind" % "jaxb-api" % "2.1"` in my build.sbt

@Bask.ws was actually right, I needed **JAXB**.

You can checkout the [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.1)

Comment: thank you so much for this answer. I was using the play framework 2.6 starter project.